# image not store in db using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am file field to upload image using paperclip through this link `http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip`  and I want to store uploaded image in db:

And I am generating paperclip in my users model name `photo` through below commands

```
 rails generate paperclip user photo
    rake db:migrate
```

And I add below lines in my users model:

```
has_attached_file :photo,:storage => :database,
                  :styles => { :small => "90x90>" },
                  :url  => "/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                  :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

    validates_attachment_presence :photo
    validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg']
```

below is my view page:

```
<%= form_for(:UploadImage, :html => { :id => "uploadimage", :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
<table width="100%">
    <% @user_basic.each do |ub| %>
    <tr>
        <td width="45%" align="right">
            <%= image_tag ub.photo.url(:small) %>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <%= f.file_field :photo %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
<table width="92%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <div class="button" style="margin-right:60px;">
                <%= f.submit "Next", { :class => "buttonSearch"} %>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

And is my controller:

```
  def create
    @blah = params[:photo]
    @user_basic=User.find(current_user.id)
    #user = User.find_by( photo_file_name: current_user.photo_file_name )

    render 'new'
  end
```

But my image not store in db. Why? kindly suggest me, waiting for your reply. 
Thanks

Comment: did you give write permission on the upload directory?

Comment: no, because I am new to using paperclip

Comment: I am not using user controller, I am using another controller name "UploadImage" and I have edit my post.

Comment: I know you didn't ask this but it's a bad idea to store the image data in your database.  Are you by any chance doing this because you're on Heroku or a shared server which doesn't allow local file saving and can't be bothered to get Amazon S3 set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Rails 4, you'll need to use [`strong params`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) to pass the data to the model (if you're creating a new `User` record), and as noted by `Teguh Syahmar`, you'll have to save the data (you're not doing that currently)

Here's some code which should work:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
    match :update_image, via [:get, :post]
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_attached_file :photo,
       :styles => { :small => "90x90>" },
       :url  => "/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
       :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/users/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
end

def update_image
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @user.update!(user_params) if request.post?
end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:other, :user, :data, :photo)
end

#app/views/users/update_image.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= image_tag @user.photo if defined?(@user.photo) %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am using your post but getting error "Cannot load storage module 'Database'"

Comment: You want to use `:storage => :filesystem` in your model, or just miss the `:storage` option out as `:filesystem` is the default.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply! As Greame mentioned, you don't need to use `storage: :database` as it's the default

Comment: We can go to chat if you want more help?

Answer (score 0):

To actually upload the file, the rails user needs to have write permission on the upload directory.

If you know the user that runs the Rails server,

```
chown -R <rails_user>:<rails_user> <rails_root>/public/assets/users/
```

If you do not know the user that runs the Rails server,

```
chmod -R a+w <rails_root>/public/assets/users/
```

Answer (score 0):

create entry for the model first it will automatically upload and store the file information

add this in your UserController#create

```
@user = User.new(params.require(:UploadImage).permit(:photo))
@user.save
```

CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

You are not making any attempt to update the User model in your `UploadImage` controller hence why the image is not included.

I'm not sure why you need a different controller; `photo` is just another attribute of the `User` model, just like username, password, email etc.

Presumably you already have a working `UsersController` with index, new, create etc. actions for creating users?  Given you have added `photo` as a mandatory attribute to the `User` model, you should find that your existing UsersController is now unable to add new users since there is no ability to add the photo.

To help you get it working you could just add:

```
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
```

to the new (and edit) views of your user, setting `multipart: true` as you did on your current view.

Then include `:photo` in your strong parameters.  For example...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    ...
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:photo)   # plus whatever other user attributes you have
  end
end
```